# Gradle signing.properties can no longer be found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was using the following code in my app's build.gradle to load in my signing properties for signing my app.  My signing.properties was in the project root folder (not app)

Upgrading to the latest Gradle/Android Gradle plugin it now reports signing.properties not found and I have to move my signing properties to the module root folder.

How can I open the file from the project root as before?  I share my signing.properties between mobile and wear apps.

```
...
def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
            props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
} else {
    println 'signing.properties not found'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject the path into the subprojects. I haven't tested the following, but it will hopefully give you the basic idea.

In your root project's *build.gradle* file, add:

```
subprojects {
    ext.signingPropsFile = rootProject.file('signing.properties')
}
```

Then whenever a subproject needs to read the file, it can use the following in its build script:

```
if (signingPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def props = new Properties()
    props.load(signingPropsFile.newReader('UTF-8'))
    ...
}
```

I strongly recommend that you specify a charset when loading a text file. If your properties file doesn't use UTF-8, then change the above from "UTF-8" to "    ISO8859_1" (which is the character encoding that your example assumes).

**Note** You can actually use `rootProject.file()` directly in your subprojects, but if you move the file, then you will have to update all your subprojects' build files as well. Hence configuration injection is a better approach.

Comment: I'll give this a try, although my current method works and I don't move project structure this looks far tidier.